# T-SNE Python application to experimental data

Tags: python, algorithm, data-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I have experimental data that I have read and saved in a dictionary. Each position has a different array from the data of each experiment. I hav to use a T-SNE algorithm to analyze the data and find similarities and differences in order to see when the tissue analyzed in the experiment is damages. Any explained code examples about how to apply T-SNE to experimental data would be every useful.

Comment: Please provide an minimal reproducible example, avoid links to data, especially if on a private drive. You can create sample data by using: ```df1.iloc[:10].to_dict()``` and post that here. Try to reduce the data to recreate the problem as short and simple as possible

Comment: I have a file with 3 million data points and a piece of code that processes it and stores it in an array of 38 positions, each of which has 80000 data points or so, i reduced it to 5 thousand datapoints with that function so in reality I am storing 38x5000 datapoints. Should I send you the file example and my piece of code?